# File is readable but fails to be included

Tags: php

I have a file where all the include files will be listed. I'm facing this unknown error.
There's a class file in **/class/class.user.php** and then there's this include file in **/includes/_inc_include.php**

Now, when I run :-

```
var_dump(is_readable('../class/class.user.php'));
```

It returns **true**
But when I try to include it using :-

```
include '../class/class.user.php';
```

It gives error :- **include(../class/class.user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Try the absolute path to file. Does it include?

Comment: I think you might want to try and use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classes/class.user.php';` (or what ever the path maybe) this should always work

Comment: @SuperDJ
That didn't work. It took me to the root folder, that is /www if I add what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned that you are trying to **include** this file, however the error you're getting is for a **require**

Is it likely that you may have required this file from one of the other files that you are including from  **/includes/_inc_include.php** ?

The error message you got, would also contain the file path and the line number of the resulting error, that should help trace the error causing **require**

Comment: It was actually include error, I by mistakenly wrote required.